# EXTJS tree panel disable selection change

Tags: javascript, extjs, selection, treepanel

I have tree panel:

```
        xtype : 'treepanel',
        itemId : 'field-tree-command-metas',
        region : 'center',
        hideHeaders : true,
        rootVisible : false,
        emptyText : 'No Commands Available',
        deferEmptyText : true,
        bufferedRenderer : false,
        reference : 'treeCommandMetas',
        bind : {
            selection : '{bindSelection}'
        },
        listeners : {
            boxready : function() {
                var treeView = this.getView();
                treeView.refresh();
            }
        },
        columns : [ {
            xtype : 'noicontreecolumn',
            dataIndex : 'name',
            flex : 1,
            nodeIconsProvider : function(record) {
                if (record.isLeaf()) {
                    return [ '<i class="' + Glyphs.getIconClass('square-o', 'size-14px') + '"></i>' ];
                }

                if (record.isExpanded()) {
                    return [ '<i class="' + Glyphs.getIconClass('folder-open-o', 'fa-lg') + '"></i>' ];
                }

                return [ '<i class="' + Glyphs.getIconClass('folder-o', 'fa-lg') + '"></i>' ];
            }
        } ],
        displayField : 'name',
        store : 'Plugin.scheduler.store.CommandMetaStore'
```

On form loaded in this tree a record is selected.
Is it possible to disable other selections? I mean that if something in tree is selected, user cannot change selection.
Tried 'disableSelection:true' but it disables all selections, I would like selection made by default visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setLocked` to disable other selections:

```
treepanel.getSelectionModel().setLocked(true);
```

If you want to enable selections you can just use the reverse:

```
treepanel.getSelectionModel().setLocked(false);
```

I have an example here using ExtJS 4.2.1: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nqf

Answer (score 0):

Implement the beforeselect listener and make it return false to disable the mouse click selection:

```
listeners:{
    boxready : your boxready function,
    beforeselect :function(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then whenever you click any row of the tree,the selection won't change.

here's the api explanation:

> **beforeselect**( this, record, index, eOpts )
>   Fired before a record is selected. If any listener returns false, the selection is cancelled.
>   Please refer [api doc here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-beforeselect).

Comment: tried, disables all selections, not depends how they was selected (EXTJS 5.1)